# Simplify JavaScript in dynamics365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming

I have a function in js and inside that I have two condition checks, how can I simplify this. I am using this in d365

Looks like i have written complex code, can you help to simplify

```js
function selectedNeedSupport(executionContext) {
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  let selectedItem = formContext.getAttribute("neededsupport").getValue();
  if (selectedItem != null && selectedItem.includes(9)) {
    formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(true);
    if (selectedItem != null && selectedItem.includes(8)) {
      formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Application").setVisible(true);
    } else {
      formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Application").setVisible(false);
    }
  } else {
    formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(false);
    if (selectedItem != null && selectedItem.includes(8)) {
      formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Application").setVisible(true);
    } else {
      formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Application").setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to check if selectedItem includes 9 and then also includes 8, is that correct?

Comment: yes, it checks 9->if 9 is there then show a field-> if 8 is there then show a tab . could be both or any one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tests and booleans. Use the tests instead of true and false:

```
const nine = selectedItem?.includes(9)    
const eight = selectedItem?.includes(8)

formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(nine && !eight);
```

for example

Answer (score 1):

```js
function selectedNeedSupport(executionContext) {
  const selectedItem = formContext.getAttribute("neededsupport").getValue();
  const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(selectedItem?.includes(9));
  formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Application").setVisible(selectedItem?.includes(8));  
}
```